# Compare two files and output with LIKE values

Tags: batch-file, vlookup

I'm trying to write a batch script to compare two files and provide output where column 4 matches.
The challenge is in File1, the fourth column sometimes has a domain (i.e. ctbri) before the user ID.
When I currently run my script, I expected at least an output of 'jjane' but no file is produced.
Any assistance on this would greatly be appreciated.

**File1:**
CTBRI,101828,Joe Joe,**ctbri\jjoe**
MIDET,187285,Jane Jane,**jjane**

**File2:**
FinRpt_Coor,GroupID,Group_Provider,**jjoe**
FinRpt_Coor,GroupID,Group_Provider,**jjane**

**Output:**
jjoe
jjane

**Current Script:**

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Load File1 as lookup table:
for /F "tokens=4 delims=," %%a in (File1.txt) do (
set "filename=%%~a"
set "col4[!filename: =_!]=%%~a"


 )

rem Process File2:
for /F "tokens=4 delims=," %%a in (File2.txt) do (
set "filename=%%~a"

    for /F %%f in ("!filename: =_!") do if defined col4[%%f] (

        echo !col4[%%f]! >> Output.txt
    )
)
```

Comment: It works as expected. I guess there is somewhere a whitespace at the end of jjane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix your first `FOR` loop to remove the optional domain.

```
for /F "tokens=4 delims=," %%a in (File1.txt) do (
    set "filename=%%~a"
    set "col_name=!filename: =_!"
    set "col_name=!col_name:*\=!"
    set "col4[!col_name!]=%%~a"
)
```

Comment: Got it working!  Good stuff.  When the line in second file 'FinRpt_Coor,,,jjane' is missing values in position 2 and 3, it doesn't work though.  Why would it not evaluate 4th position when 2nd and 3rd is blank?